# Why does my tqdm progress bar does not update itself in SublimeREPL console?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, carriage-return, sublimerepl, tqdm

The python tqdm progress bar is not properly working with the SublimeREPL console

[image: following picture]).

**Question:** Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Perhaps this might be a case for raising an issue with SublimeREPL?